# Debugging EXE files built with Scons in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, exe, scons

I am using Scons based custom command to build C++ files.

It creates separate directory of the build that contains .EXE file.

I want to know: how to debug that .exe file in Eclipse CDT?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a run configuration, specifying the full path of the exe. (Be sure that the your exe is compiled with debug symbols).

If I remember correctly, Eclipse open a windows asking you to specify the location of the source code when you are running an external executable. Just set the path, and you are good to go.